# Cannot find the dezalgo file and cannot work gulp-sass

Tags: node.js, gulp-sass

Installed Node.js and proceeded to install gulp (copied the necessary files) Run the following commands on the command line:

```
npm -v
npm -i
npm i
npm i npm-check-updates -g
ncu -u

All dependencies match the latest package versions :)
```

But when I entered the command gulp

```
C:\Open\OSPanel\domains\Compulink>gulp
    module.js:557
        throw err;
        ^

    Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-sass'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:555:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:482:25)
        at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Open\OSPanel\domains\Compulink\gulpfile.js:4:20)
        at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
```

I try to solve this problem about this command

```
C:\Open\OSPanel\domains\Compulink>npm install gulp-sass --save-dev
npm WARN opencart-project@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! path C:\Open\OSPanel\domains\Compulink\node_modules\npm\node_modules\dezalgo
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Open\OSPanel\domains\Compulink\node_modules\npm\node_modules\dezalgo' -> 'C:\Open\OSPanel\domains\Compulink\node_modules\npm\node_modules\.dezalgo.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-01-11T14_14_39_229Z-debug.log
```

But the new error is.`
File dezalgo

Answer (score 1):

The problem solved with help a command sequences. In first I clean the cache

```
npm clean cache
```

And beginning again

```
1)npm -v
2)npm i npm check updates g
3)npm i npm check updates
4)npm i -g gulp
5)npm install gulp-sass --save-dev
```

dezalgo not remove and setup gulp-sass module completed without errors